# how to send user info which is stored in sqlite database to another user and how to store current location in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, geolocation, android-sqlite

I am stuck at a point and can't figure it out how can I manage to send user's data which is stored in the database to another user with admin privileges after user just press a button in an app and display this info on admin's screen.

Till now I am done with the database to store user info during registration, I am new to android development and have just basic knowledge is there any better way in which i can possibly do that please let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I assume you access your SQLite with a content provider/resolvers. You have to make them available to other apps, at which point they can access your data. Starting reading about it here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Think about why you can easily use content provider/resolver to see all gallery photos, it works the same way. It is because the photos are stored in a publicly available SQLite database and by using content provider you can access or even modify them.